# Step function S3 putObject integration adds quotation marks

Tags: aws-step-functions

I am trying to write a file from a step function with this step:

```yaml
Put item in export:
  Type: Task
  Resource: arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:s3:putObject
  Parameters:
    Bucket: my-bucket-1234655
    Key.$: States.Format('export/items/{}.txt', $.item.id)
    Body: Foo
    ContentType: text/plain
  ResultPath: null
  Next: ...
```

I would expect the file to contain:

```
Foo
```

But it contains:

```
"Foo"
```

(I adjusted this example to only use "foo" but in reality the content is xml)

I tried [intrinsic function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html#asl-intrsc-func-json-manipulate) but there is nothing to replace things in a string, also i believe the error sits within the s3 http caller.

I know i could write a simple lambda, but I would really like to use the sdk integration.

Comment: Hey there ! I've got the same issue with .html documents, how did you manage to resolve this ?

Comment: I used a simple Lambda Function to implement this. If you like i can lookup the code and post it here. Would you like that?

Comment: In case anyone else is wondering, it does seem like this Step Functions SDK integration is just broken. It always adds quotes to the content provided in the Body sent to s3. At least, I can't figure out any way to change it. Send in bug reports to Step Functions team via AWS Support.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably guessed by now, the behaviour you are looking for is not possible via this mechanism.

The entire [State Language](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-amazon-states-language.html), including the `$` notation and intrinsic functions, operates on JSON objects and (crucially to your question) returns JSON objects. Since there is no way to represent string values in JSON without quoting them, it is simply not possible to achieve the behaviour you originally intended.

Comment: I don’t see your point, why should the implementation not be able to take the value from body an omit the quotation? I implemented this in a lambda, exactly like this. Please enlighten me

Comment: to put it another way, imagine you were to JSON write a file with body `foo` it would not be parseable by any JSON reader. However if it contained `"foo"` it would be parseable, as it is valid JSON. The same principle applies in reverse here: the State Language is writing the output as a valid JSON file and therefore contains quotations

Comment: and on top of that, if you would like to read the file without quotes, strictly you should json parse it first. For example, in python (my language of choice), `json.loads('"foo"')` (note the quotations) returns the string `foo`

Comment: Lets agree to disagree, i see no use in only using s3 with json and yes building my own workaround was easy. In my opinion it is either a bug or (really unlikely) a design flaw where someone assumes that everything which will be written into s3 will be encapsulated by quotation marks. I needed to put xml in there, and xml does not like files starting with quotation marks… thank you for inviting me into your perspective and taking the time

Comment: Haha ok, I'm not disagreeing with you, just saying that to answer your question, specifically you say you would rather not use lambda and instead use the native integration. It's not my opinion, the native integration is designed for interoperability with json (which I would say is a design choice, rather than a flaw), and for custom solutions the only route is to go with lambdas.